# How to register Micrometer Timer with SLA and tags?

Tags: java, spring-boot, prometheus, micrometer

I'm trying to migrate my Prometheus metrics to micrometer but now I'm stuck with one thing here...

At the moment I have a Prometheus histogram configured as follows:

```
private static final Histogram REQUEST_DURATION = Histogram
        .build("http_request_duration_milliseconds", "Duration in milliseconds for processing a request.")
        .labelNames("http_method", "http_status", "java_class", "java_method")
        .buckets(10, 25, 50, 100, 500, 1000)
        .register();
```

So for switching to Micrometer I replaced it as follows:

```
Timer.builder("http.request.duration")
            .description("Duration in seconds for processing a request.")
            .sla(Duration.ofMillis(10), Duration.ofMillis(25), Duration.ofMillis(50), Duration.ofMillis(100), Duration.ofMillis(500), Duration.ofMillis(1000), Duration.ofMillis(5000))
            .register(registry);
```

Ok. Let's see how I want to use it... At the moment I simply call

```
REQUEST_DURATION.labels(httpMethod, httpStatus, javaClass, javaMethod).observe(milliseconds);
```

So I replaced this to

```
Metrics.timer("http.request.duration",
            "http.method", httpMethod,
            "http.status", httpStatus,
            "java.class", javaClass,
            "java.method", javaMethod)
            .record(Duration.ofNanos(nanoseconds));
```

But the problem now is, that Micrometer complains that I previously configured the metric without those tags. Of course I did, because I don't know the values at that point. Here the Exception:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Prometheus requires that all meters with the same name have the same set of tag keys. There is already an existing meter containing tag keys []. The meter you are attempting to register has keys [http.method, http.status, java.class, java.method].`

Ok. So I thought, then let's specify the buckets with the `Metrics.timer` call. But that doesn't work because there is no method for passing these values.

So... How can I set the `sla` buckets **and** the `tags` for my metric?

Comment: Ok.. just realized that I should use `Timer` instead of `DistributionSummary` in this case. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I got the answer on [Micrometer slack channel](http://slack.micrometer.io/). The Micrometer-way of solving this, is not to register the metric itself but instead to **register a filter** as follows:

```
registry.config().meterFilter(new MeterFilter() {
    @Override
    public DistributionStatisticConfig configure(Meter.Id id, DistributionStatisticConfig config) {
        if (id.getName().equals("http.request.duration")) {
            return DistributionStatisticConfig.builder()
                    .sla(Duration.ofMillis(10).toNanos(),
                         Duration.ofMillis(25).toNanos(),
                         Duration.ofMillis(50).toNanos(), 
                         Duration.ofMillis(100).toNanos(),
                         Duration.ofMillis(500).toNanos(),
                         Duration.ofMillis(1000).toNanos(), 
                         Duration.ofMillis(5000).toNanos())
                    .build()
                    .merge(config);
        }
        return config;
    }
});
```

When pushing a metric value using `Metrics.timer(...)` as above Micrometer will call this filter and apply all the configuration specified here. This filter is only called on meter initialization, i.e. when `Metrics.timer(...)` is called the first time with this specific `name` and `tags`. So we don't have to worry about performance here.

Answer (score 4):

First, it is best to use dot separators between name parts. This keeps the metric vendor-neutral so if you ever decide to ship to something other than Prometheus, it works! In other words, best to record it as `http.request.duration`. When the Prometheus naming convention is applied, it will appear as `http_request_duration_seconds`.

If this is a Spring Boot application, you can declare the SLAs in a [property-based meter filter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#_per_meter_properties):

```
management.metrics.distribution.sla.http.request.duration=10ns,25ns,50ns,100ns,500ns,1000ns,5000ns
```

If you are on Spring Boot 1.x, you'll have to escape the name as documented [here](http://micrometer.io/docs/ref/spring/1.5#_per_meter_properties).

As an aside, Spring already [automatically records](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-metrics-spring-mvc) request duration with a metric named `http_server_requests`. It doesn't have Java class and Java method on it, but has method and status, and a few other things that you don't have here. You have an opportunity to override `WebMvcTagsProvider` to provide additional tags (including Java class and method):

```
@Bean
WebMvcTagsProvider requestTags() {
   return customProvider; // can be extended from DefaultWebMvcTagsProvider
}
```

There is a `handler` parameter to `WebMvcTagsProvider#httpRequestTags` that you can infer the type and method from.

Comment: Oh cool! Are these properties already available in Spring Boot 1? Because in my case I cannot upgrade to version 2 yet.

Comment: You can include `micrometer-spring-legacy` and `micrometer-registry-prometheus` as dependencies in your Spring Boot 1 application and you are ready to go. No need to instrument your MVC endpoints/controllers manually. Additionally you get a whole bunch of JVM metrics auto-configured for free.

Comment: Thanks for the hint with the dots. I already had this in my code but forgot to update it here. I updated my code now.

Comment: Regarding the `http_server_requests`... I know that Spring already records it. But it does not record the java class and method name but only the path. Furthermore it does not configure these buckets,... but I guess now that I could set the buckets using a configuration parameter.

Comment: @Ethan Updated the answer to show you how you can add Java class/method to Spring's default instrumenation. In general, we don't add SLAs/percentiles/etc to timers by default, but rather allow you to add them as you see fit through properties like this.